# inputで入力したリストの番号に該当するリストの中身を出力したい

Tags: python

リストの番号に該当するものを出力したい。

リストの番号を入力し、該当する数字を出力したいです。
以下のコードだと 0を入力したらa, 1を入力したらb といった感じです。

**試したこと**
以下のコードを試したけどだめだった。

**現状のコード:**

```
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
value = int(input(i))
if value == i:
    ans = ls[i]
    print(ans)
```

Comment: 「上のコードを試したけどだめだった。」とはどうダメだったのでしょうか？また、これは”試したこと”ではないですよ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
value = int(input())
ans = ls[value]
print(ans)
```